# Phonegap sql query return undefined ONLY on device

Tags: android, sql, database, cordova

I'm facing a problem with phonegap on Android.

Windows 7 x64
Phonegap 2.6

My app run ok in the simulator (android 4.3) all the queries seems fine.
When i deploy on my Nexus 7 (android 4.4, but i've tried on a android 2.3 device with same results) i get an "undefined" error from ALL the sql statement.

Error codes does not help because return "0" or "undefined" with no other descrptions.

The query are simple SELECT's, the object called with openDatabase it's valid.

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot
Rob

Answer (score 0):

To extend with some code, for example the query:

```
function gotoLinks(){
  var db_do_query = db_obj.db_open;
  var db_res_lin = db_do_query.transaction(db_obj.db_select_lin, db_obj.db_query_error);
}

  //select all links from db
  this.qry_lin_success = function (tx, results) {
      //do things with resulset
  }



  this.db_select_lin = function queryDB(tx){
      tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY lnk_titolo ASC", [], db_obj.qry_lin_success, db_obj.db_query_error);
  }
```

Works perfectly in emulator but return "undefined" in device.

Thanks 
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up on using the SQLite cordova plugin, but this problem is really weird...
Thanks
Rob